# Japan work visa and tickets for 5 family members?

Tags: japan

I've got a job offer from Japan, I'll be relocating with family, 2 adults, 3 kids.

1. As a visa requirement, I have to mention entry and departure dates on the visa form. What do I put in the case of a work visa (stay for more than 1 year)?
2. For the visa application, does booking of ticket (not buying) will be ok, or do I need to buy for all 5 family members? Surely I'll be buying them, but after we get the visa.
3. Can I buy one-way tickets or do I need to buy return tickets? I want to save money here.

Answer (score 4):

Talk to your employer. Have they gotten a certificate of eligibility for you yet?

Here's what the [Japanese Embassy in the UK](http://www.uk.emb-japan.go.jp/en/visa/CoE.html) states are required to apply for a work visa:

> Once a Certificate of Eligibility has been obtained, the applicant should bring in:
>   1. Valid passport
>   2. One visa application form (sample), completed and signed
>   3. One passport-sized photograph approx. 45mm x 45mm (taken within the last 6 months)
>   4. Original Certificate of Eligibility
>   5. One photocopy of Certificate of Eligibility

Your local embassy may have different requirements.

Comment: I've called the Embassy of Japan in Islamabad, Pakistan, and got answers in case of work visa as:

1 - Leave blank the date of entry and departure and write "not determined" in intended period of stay.

2 - There is no need to buy or book ticket before processing of Visa

3 - After Visa stamp buy one way ticket for all family members.

4 - Leave airport of entry and airline as blank